# Can you give me some clarification about Symfony2 Queries of Doctrine

Tags: symfony

Please any one can explain those `Doctrine` instruction on `Symfony2` framework

```
1. $academicYear = $em->getRepository('ComAkSolutionsSmsUserBundle:AcademicYear')
                        ->find($id);

2. public function manageAcademicClassAction($classId, Request $request)
   {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $academicClass = $em->getRepository('ComAkSolutionsSmsUserBundle:AcademicClass')
                ->find($classId);



    $academicYear = $em->getRepository('ComAkSolutionsSmsUserBundle:AcademicYear')
                ->find($academicClass->getAcademicYearId());


3. $students = $em->getRepository('ComAkSolutionsSmsUserBundle:StudentProfile')
                        ->findBySectionId($sectionId);  

4. $teacherProfile = $em->getRepository('ComAkSolutionsSmsUserBundle:TeacherProfile')
                        ->findOneByUser($user);
```

Comment: I'm guessog your first query should have been $academicClass = ...

Comment: Hi i am using in this function like this

Comment: public function manageAcademicClassAction($classId, Request $request)
    {
        
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        
        //$classId is the AcademicClassId
        // Get the AcademicClass
        $academicClass = $em->getRepository('ComAkSolutionsSmsUserBundle:AcademicClass')
                    ->find($classId);
        
        $academicYear = $em->getRepository('ComAkSolutionsSmsUserBundle:AcademicYear')
                    ->find($academicClass->getAcademicYearId());}

Comment: Challenging to read code in comments.  Just update your question so you get the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[find()](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-primary-key) is a method in the base [doctrine repository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html) to lookup a record by primary key. The first 2 examples are the same, you are just looking up different repositories.

Your 3rd and 4th examples are [custom repositories](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) and implement their own methods findBySectionId() and findOneByUser().

Comment: Since your new here, please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if you think it answered your question. Cheers.